# Python library to detect specific sound

Tags: python, audio

I need python software that "listens" to the computer sound output and returns when it identifies a specific sound that has been chosen by the user.

Comment: Do you mean detecting a particular frequency, for instance 8000 Hz? Or a particular melody? Or a word such as "Hello"? Potentially spoken by various different voices?

Comment: The sound is water splashing ( what you hear when you drop something in it)